# How to execute a symfony script more than 20min in browser (use an API with more than 1000 different lines to find 5 of) firefox failled timeout mess

Tags: php, firefox, time, timeout, execution

```
$limit=5;
for($t=1;$t<= $limit;) {
    //on recupere la date-1
    $dateTo = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($dateTo.' - 1 day'));
    $dateToFormatte = strtotime($dateTo);
    $day = date('dmY', $dateToFormatte);
                        
    //on cherche la same value
    $values = $ApiServicePlus1->getVar($day);
    if($values['left'] == $values2->getVar()) {
        dd($values['left'], $values2->getVar());
        $t++;
}
```

This script is a callback to an API, I calculated simply that it takes normally about 1 hour ton find 5 lines, in Google Chrome it's failing with a timeout message after 2 min, I saw that we can changing `network.http.keep-alive.timeout` and `network.http.response.timeout` value in firefox with typing `about:config` in search bar, I set theirs for 7200 sec, I restarted the computer and after 2 minutes it's failing, The code concern public users si I can't do that in a shell...
Is something to know that I ignore about Firefox or PHP scripts duration information for having 1 or 2 hours before timeout failing ?

Comment: I must to say that I change before the max_execution_time value to more than 7200 in php.ini, I have 2 php.ini in /etc/php/8.1/cli/ and /etc/php/8.1/apache2/ both are good, but I  remark that when I tried to add a big bdd to PHPMyAdmin, I couldn't do that after changing post_max_size upload_max_filesize memory_limit, restarted the computer, changing $cfg['UploadDir'] $cfg['SaveDir'], it didn't worked, I installed it with MySQL command line... May be a fail that I couldn't resolved for changing right php.ini, I have a 8.1 php version installed, I don't remember with snap or apt get ...

Comment: _"The code concern public users si I can't do that in a shell..."_ - please be more specific here. If you need to execute a process that takes 2+ hours via the user's browser, then most likely something must be quite wrong conceptually already.

Comment: I wanted to offer for subscribers have an algorithm for horses racing prediction, it must be 6 sames racing in fews years to sort, but now I found that the horses datas is delete after fews days into the data API, it's dead, I can't do anything about that without horses data... Don't matter with it...

Answer (score 1):

It's seems it is working now, I was quiet with the php.ini value, max_execution_time, I find an issue, changing max_execution_time for 7200, typing the command after:

```
PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=/etc/php/8.1/apache2 php
```

and

```
systemctl reload apache2
```

It reload the path to php.ini, it wasn't loaded and the browser fails with timeout message... It caused by the max_execution_time=7200 which didn't update after changing it in php.ini... Now it work better...